# SNMP trap by legitimate program?

Tags: attacks, malware, ids

Is there any way to tell if this SNMP trap is something created by a legitimate program?
[image]

Update: Hex Dump

```
    0000000: 30 82 00 ec 02 01 00 04 06 70 75 62 6c   69 63 a4 82 00 dd 06 82 00 09 2b 06 01  0........public........+..
    000001A: 04 01 ce 69 ce 69 40 04 ac 10 bd 27 02   01 06 02 02 27 69 43 03 1a 6f a5 30 82  ...i.i@....'.....'iC..o.0.
    0000034: 00 ba 30 82 00 2b 06 82 00 0a 2b 06 01   04 01 ce 69 ce 69 01 04 1b 31 37 32 2e  ..0..+....+.....i.i...172.
    000004E: 31 36 2e 31 38 38 2e 36 37 2c 31 37 32   2e 31 36 2e 31 38 39 2e 33 39 30 82 00  16.188.67,172.16.189.390..
    0000068: 12 06 82 00 0a 2b 06 01 04 01 ce 69 ce   69 02 02 02 10 df 30 82 00 1a 06 82 00  .....+.....i.i.....0......
    0000082: 0a 2b 06 01 04 01 ce 69 ce 69 03 04 0a   57 69 6e 64 6f 77 73 20 58 50 30 82 00  .+.....i.i...Windows.XP0..
    000009C: 11 06 82 00 0a 2b 06 01 04 01 ce 69 ce   69 04 02 01 01 30 82 00 15 06 82 00 0a  .....+.....i.i....0.......
    00000B6: 2b 06 01 04 01 ce 69 ce 69 05 04 05 34   2e 38 2e 36 30 82 00 10 06 82 00 0a 2b  +.....i.i...4.8.60.......+
    00000D0: 06 01 04 01 ce 69 ce 69 08 04 00 30 82   00 11 06 82 00 0a 2b 06 01 04 01 ce 69  .....i.i...0.......+.....i
    00000EA: ce 69 09 02 01 00                                                                .i....
```

Comment: Can you paste the hex dump somewhere please? I'm not typing it out manually.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no mechanism in SNMP protocol to identify the source program. 
If SNMP string is not set to default `public` then only it helps that a certain program/source can make a request. In your case you have `public` default string.

Read about [SNMP Reflection attack](https://bechtsoudis.com/hacking/snmp-reflected-denial-of-service/), source IP in the UDP packet is a spoofed address of the target, SNMP response packets get sent back to the target instead of the attacker to cause DoS.